# Ctrl plus Alt makes Visual Studio hidden form appear

Tags: vb.net

I want my application to run in the system tray, like antivirus software and such. The form should not be visible. I use the following code to hide the form on startup:

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        Me.CreateHandle()
        value = False
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
End Sub
```

That works fine. However, when I press both the Ctrl and Alt keys on my keyboard, the form appears. Google makes it seem like I am the first one to have this problem. I really hope not. How can I make my form truely hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Set your Application's FormBorder to "FixedToolWindow" (Or something like this, try all; Worked for me, but can't remember the right FormBorderStyle)